# Como esperar pelo callback Javascript

Tags: javascript, apache-cordova, callback

Estou com um problema, sei que por causa de como o javascript trabalha, mas não sei como contornar para resolver o problema.

Estou utilizando o Cordova e um função precisa utilizar a permissão de Telefone no Android.

Então antes de executar o método eu verifico se a permissão foi concedida, se não peço a permissão.

o problema é que não espera o retorno e o valor sempre fica como undefined.

Segue o código

```
var getImeiNumeber = function()
{
  if (hasReadPermission() !== true){
    requestReadPermission();

    getImeiNumeber();
  } else if (hasReadPermission() === false) {
    window.plugins.sim.getSimInfo(successCallback, errorCallback);
  }
}
```

A função

```
var successCallback = function(result)
{
  console.log(result);

  return result;
}

var errorCallback = function(error)
{
  console.log(error);
}

// Android only: check permission
var hasReadPermission = function()
{
  window.plugins.sim.hasReadPermission(successCallback, errorCallback);
}

// Android only: request permission
var requestReadPermission = function()
{
  window.plugins.sim.requestReadPermission(successCallback, errorCallback);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precisas de controlar o fluxo dessas callbacks. Uma solução seria uma função pura (que não usa nada de fora dela mesma ou dos seus argumentos).

Poderia ser assim (jsFiddle):

```
function getImeiNumeber(succ, err) {
    hasReadPermission(function(res){
        if (res) succ(res);
        else requestReadPermission(succ, err);
    }, err)
}
```

Assim ela chama `hasReadPermission`, que dá um resultado. Se o resultado fôr positivo ele chama a callback dos argumentos de `getImeiNumeber` com o valor recebido. Se fôr `false` chama `requestReadPermission` passando/continuando a callback. Assim, independentemente de usares `hasReadPermission` ou `requestReadPermission` uma das callbacks vai ser chamada.

Comment: Perfeito muito obrigado